# How can I make Python loop through sentences but it gives me words in the sentence instead of every letter in the sentence?

Tags: python, loops

I am making a basic bot in Python that you can ask it questions and it will respond. But when I was testing the code (in a 'for' loop), I wanted it to print the result to me word by word, but it prints out the output letter by letter. How do I get it to print word by word? Here's the code;

```
print("Welcome to your personal  bot assistant.")

question = input('''Ask me anything you want to know
>>> ''')

for i in question:
  print(i)
```

If I input 'hello' for example, it prints out;

h

e

l

l

o

Comment: Use `split` to split a string into a list of words, e.g. `question = input("...").split()`

Answer (score 1):

Change the for loop to this:

```py
for i in question.split():
    print(i)
```

This loops through every word in a sentence. For example, the sentence "how old am I" gave me:

how

old

am

I

However, it should be noted that if you used a full stop at the end of the input, the output would include that. To get around that, you can use: `question.replace(".", "")`.